# VSCode: override settings for the specific file formats (.md or .txt)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to override global settings only for a specific file format, like disabling IntelliSense for the `.txt` and `.md` only, and leave it enabled for everything else?

I know there is a lot a issues filed in the vscode repository regarding disabling IntelliSense for the .txt files, but there is a global option

`editor.wordBasedCompletion: false`

which could do this globally. Is there a way to override it for the `.txt` only?

UPD. Looks like there is no possibility built-in, but there is a feature request here
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11879

Please go vote for the issue, so they'd implement it faster.

Comment: This happened in January 2017.